# Need to connect a serial port that's attached to a modem to a virtual com port

Tags: python, networking, pyserial

I need to be able to connect to a raw serial connection that's connected to a modem.

The modem has an ip address and port.

This program works for one instance but is expensive for the amount of licenses I'd need and I'd prefer to code something:
http://www.serial-port-redirector.com/

It connects a remote ip to a local virtual com port.

I think it should be possible to do the same thing using pyserial but I'm struggling to understand how to do it.

This page kind of half explains it:
http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#miniterm

But I'm still lost. If anyone could help me understand how to use rfc2217 in python it'd rock.

Thanks very much!

+anything for either linux/windows would be good.